# How to commit a special Ascii character from string to a file?

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii, special-characters

I need to write a special Ascii-Chacacter (Dez 3) from a string to a file.
But i fail to get the character into a string.

In Notepad++ i can press `Alt + 03` the get [image: Ascii Dez 3] If I try it in Visual Studio nothing happens.

I have never enganged myself with encodings. Every explanation is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "I fail to get the character **into** a string"? I thought you wanted to get it **from** a string? Please show the code sample with what you've tried.

Comment: Before I can read the character from the string, I have to write it to the string.

Comment: `string foo = $"ETX: {'\x03'}";` Adding control characters invisibly to a string makes things hard to maintain. This way you can see what you're adding.

Comment: Works, thanks! If you write an answer, i can mark it as solved.